# Which css grid frameworks fix (or workaround) the div content vertical alignment issue?

Tags: css, grid

Which css grid frameworks fix (or workaround) the div content vertical alignment issue?
http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If IE7 is not relevant. you can use the CSS-property `display: table-cell` to center content vertically.

Here is an example (the image is missing, but you should get the idea):

http://jsfiddle.net/uB3pW/

You can also build a grid using this with widths, columns and all that.